# Useful C# class/methods for DFS and BFS program

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have an XML file of nodes with their connections. Something like:

```
<Graph>
  <Node Name = "A">
    <ConnectsTo>B</ConnectsTo>
    <ConnectsTo>H</ConnectsTo>
  </Node>
  <Node Name="B"></Node>
  <Node Name="C">
    <ConnectsTo>E</ConnectsTo>
  </Node>
  <Node Name="D">
    <ConnectsTo>C</ConnectsTo>
  </Node>
  <Node Name="E"></Node>
  <Node Name="F">
    <ConnectsTo>D</ConnectsTo>
    <ConnectsTo>G</ConnectsTo>
  </Node>
  <Node Name="G">
    <ConnectsTo>E</ConnectsTo>
    <ConnectsTo>I</ConnectsTo>
  </Node>
  <Node name="H">
    <ConnectsTo>C</ConnectsTo>
    <ConnectsTo>J</ConnectsTo>
    <ConnectsTo>G</ConnectsTo>
  </Node>
  <Node name="I">
    <ConnectsTo>E</ConnectsTo>
  </Node>
  <Node name="J">
    <ConnectsTo>A</ConnectsTo>
  </Node>
</Graph>
```

Now, I will map those nodes using either BFS or DFS and print how nodes are being mapped/retrieved.

Sample Prompt :

```
Choose (1)DFS (2)BFS : 1
Choose Starting Vertex : A

Result : 

A B
A H J
A H C E
A H G E
A H G I E
```

Am I on the right track of re-arranging first the nodes in hierarchy? What classes will be useful for this (rearranging and future process)? Subclass of `Graph`? `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your specific requirements, though, you might not need to write any custom code for the traversal. [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) lets you use the familiar LINQ methods with XML data. That's what I would recommend unless you have custom requirements that necessitate using DFS or BFS explicitly.

If you must do DFS or BFS, it's pretty easy. To my knowledge, there aren't any built-in methods that let you do one or the other. But they're not hard to write. Standard data structures are all that you need. Depth-first traversal is typically done with recursion:

```
void Dfs(NodeType node)
{
    foreach (var child in node.Children)
    {
        Dfs(child);
    }
    // here, output node information
}
```

The easiest way to do breadth-first traversal is with a queue:

```
void Bfs(NodeType node)
{
    var theQueue = new Queue<NodeType>();
    theQueue.Enqueue(node);
    while (theQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        var n = theQueue.Dequeue();
        // output node data
        // then add each child to the queue
        foreach (var child in n.Children)
        {
            theQueue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're searching, then instead of "output node data", you'd insert your comparison code, and potentially an early out if you want to exit with the first item found.

Answer (score 0):

Would the result for :

```
Choose (1)DFS (2)BFS : 1
Choose Starting Vertex : A

Result :
```

not be

```
A B
A B H
A B H J
A B H J C
A B H J C E
A B H J C E G
A B H J C E G I
```

???
maybe I already forgot how to do DFS, but my understanding was that you go as far in the "tree" as possible, then only go back to a previous node when there are no more nodes to traverse for the current node. No nodes should be lost in the process.

Answer: I would probably just use a LinkedList as a stack, and that should serve your purposes just fine.

Comment: Why would you use a linked list as a stack when you could use `System.Collections.Generic.Stack`?

Comment: Because I didn't know there was one! I'm relatively new to C#